# SSIS Sort component fails if there is just one input record

Tags: sorting, ssis

There is something weird happening with SSIS Sort component. It fails if there is just one input record. We usually receive more than one record so it never failed before. In today's input file there was just one record and the process failed. I checked the data itself and it looks good. After playing with different scenarios I figured out that if I add at least one more record to the input file the process works and inserts both records into the destination table.
As you can see in the screenshot one record is coming to the Sort 1 but nothing is coming out.
Any Idea what's wrong with this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Huh, nothing in the documentation about the component requiring more than 1 row https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/sort-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15  Look around in the output, any chance there are other errors?

Comment: Nope. That's the only error

Comment: Ideally it should work, but if you need a work around please have a look at https://guru-msbi.blogspot.com/2013/07/using-merge-join-without-sort.html

Comment: I've ran into this exact same issue/error when trying to process a single record... Same (unhelpful) error message code as yours too:  [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Sort Sales Orders" (3184) failed with error code 0x80070057 while processing input "Sort Input" (3187).  I'll try your work around, but would prefer a much more elegant solution than dummy records :)

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround I ended up creating two dummy records and then removing them after Merge Join. The reason for creating two records and not just one is - if nothing is coming through this flow, one dummy record would cause the Sort fail with the same error.

[image]